# SELECT geometry FROM spaces WHERE geometry ARE WITHIN OR OVERLAP polygons FROM OTHER table

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I've got two tables, one containing LINESTRINGs and one containing POLYGONEs.

I would like to select all the LINESTRINGs that are containing within the outer boundary of all the POLYGONs combined.

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3 and PostGIS 2.1.

Is that possible from within the WHERE statement?

Comment: I've tried something like  WHERE ST_Contains("geometry", (SELECT geometry FROM POLYGONs)), but that slows the query down very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, using **[ST_Contains](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html)**

```
SELECT lines.*
FROM lines, polygons
WHERE ST_Contains(polygons.geom, lines.geom)
```

Comment: It worked with ST_Contains(polygons.geom, lines.geom). Thanx.

Comment: Sorry, I got the order mixed up. Corrected now. Glad you got it working.